# Navbar only shows as non-functionaing hamburger menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar, hamburger-menu

I received an email from a client who said that the "hamburger menu wasn't working" on our website. I assumed he was looking at the site on a mobile device because the hamburger menu should only appear when the screen size drops below 784px. Otherwise, there should be a nice big navbar with drop-down menus. But it turns out he was looking at it on a desktop in a nice large window. He was using Windows 10 and got the same results in Firefox and Chrome. I also use Windows 10 and couldn't get this to happen in *any* of the browsers on either my home or office computer. Does anybody have an idea what's happening? Here's the website: https://goolara.com/ I hope it's just him, but I'm worried we might be losing potential clients if they can't get past the home page.

Comment: Ask him to load the page with the Chrome inspector open and to send you a screenshot of the console tab.  Perhaps there will be a stylesheet or JS include failing to load, preventing the site from displaying properly to him.

Answer (score 0):

The only guess I have is that some JS asset is not loading using his device. This may be caused if his connection blocks such asset from loading (firewall or something blocks it).

Here are the screenshots of your website on my browser (Chrome).

[image: Appearance on 360 x 40 resolution - Galaxy S5]

[image: Appearance on 1440 x 900 resolution]